# d3js with angular directive - each click appending new graphics instead of re-draw or updating the data

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

In `angularjs` directive on user click, i am changing the data for new  drawing. but the drawing not changing at all.. how to fix this.

here is my code :

```
link : function ( scope, element, attr ) {


            $timeout(function () {

                var phrase = scope.contractor.Type;

                scope.$watch("contractor.ActualPercentage", function ( newValue, oldvalue ) {

                    var phraseValue = [newValue, 100-newValue];
                    drawPie( phraseValue, phrase );



            function drawPie (array, phrase) {


                var width = element.width(), height = element.height(),
                radius = Math.min(width, height) / 1.2, data = array;

                if(!data.length) return;

                var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain(data)
                    .range(["#ffff00", "#1ebfc5"]);

                var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                    .outerRadius(radius - 90)
                    .innerRadius(radius - 85);

                var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                    .sort(null)
                    .value(function(d) { return d });

                var svg = d3.select("#pieGraph")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


                 var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
                      .data(pie(data))
                        .enter().append("g")
                        .attr("class", "arc");

                  g.append("path")
                      .attr("d", arc)
                      .style("fill", function(d,i) {  return color(d.data); });

                 g.append("text")
                     .text(data[0]+'%')
                     .attr("class", "designVal")
                     .style("text-anchor", "middle")


                 g.append("text")
                    .text(phrase)
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + 25 + ")")
                    .attr("class", "designPhrase")
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")

                // svg.exit().remove(); not working.

            }

                })



            }, 1000)

        }
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/o72Q5vCM3bnvP3bc7TY1?p=preview)

Comment: You can add everything inside your `watch`, so  `var drawPie`. This way, your chart will be rendered every time your data changes and I don't think you need the `$timeout`

Comment: $timeout - I am using for getting the data by delayed.

Comment: Then, your structure could be `link` - `$timeout` - `$watch` - `drawpie`

Comment: Can you post me as a answer please? - that's what i do now

Comment: @RazvanBalosin - as like your suggestion I updated my code. But still the previous drawing exist. it means i am getting no.of drawing added according to the click

Comment: Can you post a working plunker?

Comment: That example is not using AngularJS. You need to create an example with your data (exactly how you have it in your app), otherwise, I'm not gonna be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're appending items each time you click, and you're not removing anything.

Adding:

`d3.select("#pieGraph svg").remove();`

Before:

`var svg = d3.select("#pieGraph")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width)`

Will properly swap out the graphics on click. Here's an updated plnkr for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/jIiAq5VEzObkb6004DHG?p=preview

I changed the start defaultValue to 0 and commented out the $timeout. I'm not exactly sure why you are using a $timeout, but it works still with no issues once I remove it.

Comment: Yes, this is works. But is this the correct way to integrate `d3js` with angularjs.. because i should not get any side effect later

Comment: Well, your question was about how to get the pie to update properly. If there is a proper pattern for using d3 with Angular, that's a different question all together. You could possibly do things differently with an isolate scope, but I do like having only 1 watcher which you've set manually inside of the the directive itself. I don't see any potential side effects overall with this working solution.